# Чем заменить функцию strtold?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Вот такой код не собирается и выдает ошибку C3861: strtold (идентификатор не найден).

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* strtold */

int main ()
{
  char szOrbits[] = "90613.305 365.24";
  char * pEnd;
  long double f1, f2;
  f1 = strtold (szOrbits, &pEnd); // ошибка
  f2 = strtold (pEnd, NULL);      // ошибка
  printf ("Pluto takes %.2Lf years to complete an orbit.\n", f1/f2);
  return 0;
}
```

в пространстве std этой функции так же нет.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел замену в заголовке `string` на аналогичную функцию `std::stold`